# Сайт целиком на ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript

Стоит ли так делать? Чтобы по всем страницам перемещаться и общаться с сайтом без перезагрузки страницы? Да, есть минусы вроде кнопки "назад" и т.п. мелочей.

Стоит ли для таких не малозначимых операций пользоваться jquery-методом $.ajax(), или самостоятелно вручную все проделывать лучше?

Мне на такую идею возразили, мол ajax не для этого придумали - так для чего же?

Comment: Проблема с "назад" вполне решаема, но всё равно так лучше не ня)

Comment: Мне кстати тоже эта идея нравится. =)

Comment: Владимир, нравится кнопка "назад" или сайт на ajax?

Comment: кнопка назад реализуется очень просто :)

Answer (score 11):

Сайт полностью на ajax не всегда идеологический бред, например, если это не совсем сайт, а веб-приложение. В некоторых случаях обновление страницы и переход по ссылкам просто не имеет смысла и не удобно, а удобна именно имитация desktop-приложения: диалоги с кнопками и т.п. Например, приложения для торговли на бирже.

Comment: Все таки сайт и приложение несколько разные вещи.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Можно почувствовать разницу между "сайтом" и "приложением".

Comment: Если роботы завоюют мир и разрешат нам юзать компы, то оконных приложений не будет (кроме браузеров), а будет только веб. Так они будут осуществлять контроль над нами - жалкими человеками!!!

Comment: *Плюсом к ответу @cy6erGn0m:* [How I stopped worrying and learned to love the < body/>](https://speakerdeck.com/jamesgpearce/23181) by James Pearce

Answer (score 4):

Ajax создан для того, чтобы сделать отдельные страницы интерактивными.
Делать кашу из одной страницы это идеологический бред.

Comment: Хм... наверно Вы правы.

Будет интересно выслушать и других участников.

Answer (score 4):

Ajax нужен, чтобы не перегружать страницу полностью, а обновить часть контента страницы. Помимо стандартных решений типа $.ajax, jsHttpRequest и т.д. нужно понимать, что необходимы будут прерывания, иначе сайт не будет работать так, как нужно.
А вообще, согласен, делать сайты на аяксе полностью - идеологический бред :)

Answer (score 4):

согласен практически со всеми высказываниями, всё зависит от задач, которое будет решать ваш сервис: если это сайт-визитка, то в повсеметном использовании ajax нету смысла, если это сайт, на который пользователи попадают через результаты поисковых запросов - тем более, а вот если это веб-приложение, то тут отсутствие интерективности пагубно скажется на дизайне оного. А вообще лучше использовать ajax в меру: для авторизации без перезагрузки контента, для отправки сообщений, комментов, и естественно для подгрузки контента.

---

стоит ли использовать $.ajax()? да, стоит, это ускоряет разработку и отлаживание ошибок.

---

не использовать ajax в тех сферах, для которых он не был изначально придуман, не грех, главное, чтобы он гармонично вписывался в решение, не мешал юзабельности и не нагружал сервер.

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать всё. В том числе сайт на ajax, который будет и отлично индексироваться, и не уступать по функционалу обычному. Всё зависит от энтузиазма разработчика. При правильном подходе ajax даст намного большие возможности сайту, но не стоит за это браться, не имея соответствующего уровня навыков и знаний.

Answer (score 2):

Согласен с предыдущими высказывании о сайте на одном ajax. Ajax можно добавить для уменьшения трафика или работы со страницей без перезагрузки, но необходимо так же оставить и обычную навигацию, так как у кого-то может быть отключен JS.
А проблема с переходами вперед-назад в некоторых браузерах решаема: http://htmlbook.ru/html5/history

Comment: отключен js)))

Comment: неужели остались еще такие? с отключенным js

Comment: Более того - остались даже с текстовыми браузерами, хотя их и мало. В любом случае, у пользователя может оказаться устаревший браузер, плохо понимающий jQuery.

Comment: Вы не поверите, у большинства поисковых роботов JS отключен.

Comment: Пишется "ненавязчивый" аякс и все. Т.е. сперва пишется сайт с нормальной навигацией без скриптов, а потом все необходимые ссылки подменяются в js.  
Т.е. получаем сайт с аякс-навигацией, а если у юзера отключен js - то сайт без аякс навигации(кэп).

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то это уже вопрос времени, когда все начнут так делать. Во-первых, таким образом сайт работает быстрее (особенно процесс загрузки с точки зрения пользователя), во-вторых, сайт кажется более интерактивным и современным. Если обеспечить адекватную обратную совместимость (скажем, для роботов), то получаются одни плюсы.

Просто посмотрите на примеры самых популярных сайтов мира и/или рунета: «живой поиск» на Гугле и Яндексе или даже обычный сёрфинг на Фейсбуке, Вконтактике и Твитере.

По-моему «идеалогический бред» в данном случае — бояться трендов, тенденций и логичной эволюции веба.

Answer (score 0):

Если для вас кнопка «назад» — мелочь, то точно не стоит так делать. Пользователи вас возненавидят.

Comment: Я в том плане, что они решаемы.

Answer (score 0):

Помимо кнопки "назад", которую, действительно, не так сложно сэмулировать, есть еще одна "мелочь". Вы не даете пользователю возможности сохранять ссылки на страницы. Уж не знаю, о каком сайте идет речь, но и "контакты" на сайте-визитке, и ссылку на позицию в каталоге в интернет-магазине кто-нибудь захочет добавить в избранное, или передать по аське.

Я не говорю уже о том, что пользователь тупо нажал F5 по каким-то своим соображениям, и все пропало, он опять на главной :) (хотя этой ситуации можно избежать, например, через сессии или кукис, но... оно вам надо ?)

Comment: Не факт. Как фрагментом (см. твиттер с его `twitter.com/#!/username`) так и используя HTML5 History API. Вон, например, на GitHub переходы по дереву репозитория — чистейший AJAX, чтобы не обновлять всю страницу, обновляется только директория и список файлов в ней. Но все работает, слава progressive enhancement.

Comment: Не по теме, но все же... Уважаемый drdaeman, мне кажется или вы пытаетесь просто набить уважения споря со всеми и влезая в некропостинг? Это не очень хорошая практика.

Comment: @drdaeman довольно правильно отметил про решетку ИМХО. Как раз это не самая главная головная боль в данном случае.

Comment: В адресную строку можно на js без большой крови писать get-параметры, по которым отрабатывать навигацию по сайту. Я задавал(кажется вчера) вопрос на эту тему - сегодня нашел решение, [вот оно][1], если интересно.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/31384/подстановка-в-url-get-параметров

Comment: @Сергей: Не знаю, на SO комментировать (по теме) записи хоть столетней давности считалось нормальным. Так же, как и высказывание уточнений, поправок или комментариев, если они относятся к обсуждаемому вопросу.  Если я где-то пишу не по делу — извольте заминусовать, ткнуть носом и/или сообщить администрации. Если есть еще какие-либо моменты — прошу в почту, в профиле она указана.

Answer (score 0):

Если Ваша цель продвинуть сайт - не стоит этого делать. Несмотря на то, что гугль вроде как начал индексировать аякс страницы, большинство поисковых систем, все-таки, этого не делают. 
Аякс часть стоит делать в тех части сайта (навигация по меню пользователя, например), делать же перелистывание контента на нем - полная потеря индекса.

Comment: А если использовать "ненавязчивый" аякс? Все страницы будут обрабатываться как надо, поисковые машины, по идее, не потеряются ;)

Comment: если не потеряются - делайте. только помните об отключенном js у юзеров.